# Prepare for dual-booting with Windows

Tags: system-installation, dual-boot, microsoft-windows

I have a Lenovo Helix with Windows installed. I want to install elementary OS along side it.

I have searched this subject and get different responses and to be honest I don't really understand what I'm reading.

What is the correct way to prepare my machine for dual booting?

Comment: My pc freeze on selection timezone! I use ethernet cable, in try elementary my internet conection works

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Recommended System [Specifications](https://elementary.io/en/docs/installation#download-elementary-os) for elementary OS :

> - Intel i3 or comparable dual-core 64-bit processor
> - 1 GB of system memory (RAM)
> - 15 GB of disk space
> - Internet access

1. Download Elementary OS from [here](https://elementary.io/docs/installation)
2. Shrink one of your partition in windows (for example shrink 20GB)
3. Boot in to live USB or disk.
4. Now you’ll be asked to choose the language of the operating system to be installed. So select your language and click **Install elementary**.
   [image]
5. After that you will see this page, Click continue. (It's better to uncheck Download updates while installing and Install this third-party software)
   [image]
6. Choose **something else** and click **install now**.
   [image]
7. Now you will see this page which is for creating elementary partitions.
   [image]
8. Select your free space partition which had done in step 2 and click on **Add...** button. Here you will need to create at least three partitions ( `/` , `/home` and `swap` )

[image]
[image]
[image]

9. Choose your location for time zone selection and click continue.

[image]

10. Choose your language and click continue.
    [image]
11. Fill in your information and choose a strong root/administrator password and click continue.
    [image]
12. Core installation process starts wait until it finished and then restart your PC.
    [image]

**Important:** For dual-booting on UEFI mode see this [answer](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/278/cannot-boot-freya-after-installing-alongside-windows-on-uefi/#306)

Comment: I suggest that you include at least a basic description of the steps required in your answer because, if the link dies, the answer will die too.

Comment: Step 2 is the only one that answers the question (**prepare** for dual-booting), the rest is generic installation instructions. It's awfully sketchy. Do you actually need to resize the partition in Windows? Most Linux installers can do that, including Ubuntu's; have elementary removed this feature? And if resizing on Windows is necessary, how on earth does one do it? Is it even possible without third-party tools?