# Cannot boot Freya after installing alongside Windows on UEFI

Tags: release-freya, uefi, dual-boot, system-installation

I have installed elementary OS Freya on UEFI in the same way that I installed it on legacy mode.

But I can't boot to Freya and there is no Grub on start-up. I also tried to create an entry for Grub (or Grub2) with EasyBCD on Windows 8.1 and install MBR but can't find any boot loader for Freya.

Is there any other way to install Freya on UEFI?

Other Linux distributions like Fedora support UEFI by default (They create a `/boot/EFI` alongside the Microsoft boot loader).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I found my answer.

First I installed Freya in Legacy Mode, after that I converted it to UEFI using [boot repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair).

After installation, I switched bios configuration to UEFI and boot in UEFI mode using Ubuntu Live (or other live media) and I do these steps:

1. In Ubuntu first thing we need to do is remove `bios_grub` partition using GParted (Just find `bios_grub` in Flags column in GParted and delete it).
2. Then type the following commands:

   `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
    sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair`

   It will automatically scan systems and detect EFI.
3. After scanning finishes, you will see this dialog box.

[image: Boot Repair]

4. Just press **Recommended Repair**, it will apply changes (while boot repair is working, it will ask you to run some commands in Terminal).
5. Now boot the successfully repaired system and enjoy elementary OS on UEFI.