# Grub doesn't show at start up

Tags: release-loki, grub

Recently, installed Loky in dual boot mode with Win10 in my laptop. The installtion seemed to run ok. When the install program requested to restart, I did it, but the grub bootloader didn't show up, and the machine started directly to Windows. Will appreciate any suggestion that will  help me troubleshoot this problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a possible duplicate : [GRUB not showing after installing Elementary OS alongside Windows 10](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/2894/grub-not-showing-after-installing-elementary-os-alongside-windows-10)

In Windows, go to the menu and search for Command Prompt, right click on it to run it as administrator

Copy paste the command below:

```
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi
```

Comment: Good to hear! Can you please mark is as answered?

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a comment for which I at this point still lack the reputation. Does your computer have a UEFI bootloader? If so, have you ensured that [Secure Boot](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/secureboot.html) is off? (An appropriate switch can often be found in the BIOS settings menu.) Also concerning UEFI and in the case that you did in fact disable Secure Boot: Once again boot into the BIOS menu and verify the priority of your boot options: It might be that the Windows Bootloader is still taking precedence over Grub. In that case adjust things appropriately (which once again can be done in most modern BIOS settings).

Comment: Thanks for your comment. In answering your questions. Yes, secure boot is disabled as it is shown below.
[link]https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_ZOUN6JcLCXcGhtN2d0OHhGbmc[/link]
The grub bootloader was actually installed, but apparently not in the expected place. I found out when I chose F9 from the start menu (Device options). There, I found Ubuntu. See the picture below:
[link]https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_ZOUN6JcLCXYUxib1lsYUFfek0
Now, I need to know how to relocate the bootloader to the correct place.

Comment: As mentioned, relocating is typically possible in the bios menu. If not, either follow the advice of Pretzel Jones to do it from Windows, or, if booted into Elementary, you can also use efibootmgr of which a detailed description is available here: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rhinstaller/efibootmgr/master/README