# Cant boot to Windows 10 after installing eOS

Tags: dual-boot

This is on a 2012 MacBook Pro.

I followed what I think is the normal process - Installed windows 10 and then elementary choosing to install side by side.

Elementary boots up fine, but when selecting windows in grub it just goes to a black screen instantly. I have left it for a couple of hours just incase there was something going on in the background but no luck.

I have tried Ubuntu 'boot-repair', and booting from a Windows USB key but none of the boot repair methods worked.

I *think* that both installs are installed with EFI boot if that makes a difference (although I'm not entirely sure what that means)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you please take a look at - https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/2894/grub-not-showing-after-installing-elementary-os-alongside-windows-10 and tell me if that helps.

Comment: Didn't help. I can boot into elementary fine, its windows that is the problem.