# I deleted my /boot folder and it's strange but now elementary OS doesn't boot anymore

Tags: boot, grub

Stupid me, I've deleted my /boot folder with a little sudo rm * command. (I was doing two things at the same time, wrong terminal and... it's gone).

Without rebooting, I used boot-repair. When I rebooted the grub was here but I could boot into Elementary OS. I just have a black screen for 2 mins and then this message :
- Failed to boot both default and fallback entries or 
- out of memory -> Minimal bash like
Finally it goes back to grub with it's 4 entries :

- EFI/BOOT/bkpbootx64.efi
- EFI/BOOT/fbx64.efi
- EFI/Ubuntu/mmx64.efi
- System setup

I've tried to reinstall grub with the eOS LiveCD, the boot-repair iso, and various thread like [this one](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/2894/grub-not-showing-after-installing-elementary-os-alongside-windows-10) , but I still have a black screen.

Here is my boot-repair report (no internet on this computer) : 
[image: Boot repair]

Thank a lot !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've manager to get it work again. I'm pretty new to linux so don't hesitate to correct my answer in the comments with the rights terms. 
Here is the procedure : 
Boot with  a

Retrieve the mount point of the EFI partition and the System Partition:

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

In my case it was : 
    [1]=system partition = /dev/sda2
    [2]=efi partition = /dev/sda1
    [3]=disk = /dev/sda

Mount the partitions so when we can edit them with chroot :

```
sudo mount [1] /mnt
sudo mount [2] /mnt/boot/efi
for i in /dev /dev/pts /proc /sys /run; do sudo mount -B $i /mnt$i; done
sudo chroot /mnt
```

Find the kernel version installed on the system in /lib/modules or :

```
dpkg -l | grep linux-image-.*-generic
```

Reinstall the kernel :

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-image-W.X.Y-ZZ-generic
```

Install grub :

```
grub-install [3]
update-grub
```

And it should be ok. 
The only problem I have now is my splashscreen doesn't show up anymore.

Answer (score 0):

See this link. It contains the solution. https://www.howtogeek.com/114884/how-to-repair-grub2-when-ubuntu-wont-boot/