# Win8.1 and Freya dual boot

Tags: dual-boot

Can someone please give me a detailed guide of how to install elementary os freya 64bit to dual boot alongside a preinstalled win8.1? I have a sony vaio TSeries laptop. I heard there are many issues with dual boot so I guess I need a detailed course of how to do this. Thanks!

Comment: Duplicate of http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/q/16/374

Comment: Would vote for closing because of duplicate , too...

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot) is a great tutorial that I believe works with elementary too.
I recommend following [this answer on askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation/343370#343370) on creating disk partitions for your installation.
You might want to use the `Windows Partitioning Tool` withing Windows to shrink the Windows partition though, so you avoid potentially corrupting your Windows installation.

Good luck.

Answer (score -3):

Here is a tutorial.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hOz66FC0pWU

If you encounter any problems, install Boot-Repair on elementary livecd or press "try elementary" version.

Comment: That turkish thing is totally bad and wrong. Installing from within windows is no longer supported. What he wants to do is to shrink windows partition and then follow installation from bootable media.