# Install alongside windows 10 UEFI

Tags: system-installation, dual-boot, microsoft-windows

I noticed the latest version of Freya (0.3.2) has some fixes for GRUB and EFI.

Yet I would like to know the right way to install it on dual boot with Windows 10.

I've seen many tutorials with different procedures each. Is there a definitive method for installing with dual boot Windows 10 with the latest version that features these new fixes?

Some of my doubts are regarding differences between tutorials:

- Install alongside windows or Something else?
- Using boot repair after installation?
- Disable something from the windows side?

---

This is not the same as [Prepare for dual-booting with Windows](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/16/prepare-for-dual-booting-with-windows) since that method uses the "Something else" install method.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prepare for dual-booting with Windows](http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/16/prepare-for-dual-booting-with-windows)

Comment: how install ELEMENTARY OS 0.04 in a W10 SURFACE 4 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to just click "Install alongside Windows", without the need for boot repair or any other modification. It's what I did on my most recent installation.

Comment: Worked like a charm. It seems everything has been simplified over time even though most tutorials online have not been updated.

Comment: I think it is most likely that they are not updated because there is no need for a tutorial anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you've seen these other two questions but they may help.

1. [Prepare for dual-booting with Windows](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/16/prepare-for-dual-booting-with-windows?rq=1)
2. [Cannot boot Freya after installing alongside Windows on UEFI](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/278/cannot-boot-freya-after-installing-alongside-windows-on-uefi/#306)

Comment: The first answer is the common BIOS setup. The second uses boot repair and legacy mode. I believe there's no need to change to Legacy anymore.