# Not Recognising Partitions When Attempting Dual Boot install

Tags: system-installation, dual-boot

I have a dell xps 13 9350 with the i7 cores and quad hd display. I made a bootable usb for elementary OS and am able to run it from the live-USB fine. When i try to install it however, the installer gets stuck at adding a new partition and it does not recognise any of my other partitions. I am running Windows 10 and would like to install elementary alongside that.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I've flagged this question as a duplicate, it's already answered here: [Prepare for dual-booting with Windows](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/16/prepare-for-dual-booting-with-windows)

Basically, you need to make one of you Partitions smaller so you leave some space on the drive for elementaryOS which will create a new Partitions.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you organised partitions properly in earlier part of installation.

I had that problem, because windows 10 is not shutting down when you shutdown it from start menu/any icon that is meant to shutdown computer. It hibernates so that it doesn't take ages to start when you click power button on computer.- probably they wanted to have 'quick' system

This problem affects also windows files that are not accessible from Linux if it's in this hibernate mode.

So you need to use in windows command `shutdown /s /t 0`. It'll shutdown you computer completely.

You can add shortcut to your desktop or start menu with right click and add shortcut - just type command in the box.

That solved my problem with installation. :)